# How to guarantee delivery of messages in MassTransit?

Tags: c#, publish-subscribe, messaging, masstransit

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a fault-tolerant message publication solution using MassTransit. We'll focus on the simple scenario where we only need to commit a database change, and publish an event indicating that change. Because there is no (built-in) mechanism that allows an atomic "commit and publish", *when* our process crashes, we *will* get into an inconsistent state (some messages would only be committed to the database, and some might only be published to the message queue).

[This documentation page](https://masstransit-project.com/articles/outbox.html) offers a solution, where because we assume message handling is idempotent, we can rely on the entire operation to be retried in case of failure, and these partial commits will be resolved *eventually*. This is a great solution, but it only has one caveat: it assumes that the operation we are performing was triggered by a message, and if we won't send an ack, processing will be retried. This is not a reasonable assumption, as messaging is typically used only for *internal* communication inside the system, not for communication with the outside world. What should I do when I need to save-and-publish when handling an HTTP request from an external client?

One possible solution is to hack our way into the approach presented in the article, by only publishing (or sending) a message, and listening to it ourselves, then in the message handler we do the commit and the publishing of the actual event we want others to listen to. The main problem I have with this is that it assumes we never have to return anything in the HTTP response. What if we need to indicate the success or failure of the database transaction back to the HTTP client? (example: if we rely on a UNIQUE constraint to tell us whether or not we should accept the request, and we want to indicate failure to the client). We could solve it by using request-response over the message queue (with ourselves), but this is ugly and increases latency and complexity considerably, for what is actually a very common scenario.

The approach I see the most over the internet to solve this problem, is to use an outbox that is persisted to the same database we need to write to anyway, and thus we can wrap the two operations in a regular ACID database transaction. Then a background task polls this database for new events and publishes them to the message broker. Unlike other frameworks, I understand that MassTransit does not support this behavior out of the box. So I guess my question boils down to: before rushing to implement this relatively complex mechanism myself (once per database technology), is there another solution I'm missing? what is the accepted solution to this problem in the MassTransit community?

Comment: No other solution comes to my mind. We exactly have an extra storage for messages and extra task that is supposed to reliably publish from it. That solves one issue but pushes possible inconsistency down the pipeline. Note that it's not MassTransit related only.

Comment: @WiktorZychla And how did you implement the background polling? Did you assume there is only one instance of the message publisher? Because if not, this becomes quite a tricky task to implement (without flooding the message broker with duplicates).

Comment: Yes, just one. When needed, it scales horizontally, there's just another copy of the storage-publisher and the app uses round robin to pick a storage it saves to.

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked several times, in a variety of forms, here and other places. But the short answer is simple.

In your controller, write to the message broker only. Let the consumer deal with the database, in the context of consuming a reliable message, with all the nice retry and redelivery options that are available in that context. Then you get all the benefits of the InMemoryOutbox, without adding extreme complexity related to having a third-party (HTTP, database, and broker) in a single conversation.

Comment: Would you also recommend to handle database queries in the consumer only? Because that seems kind of slow rather than just having fire-and-forget jobs

Comment: Queries don't have side effects, or shouldn't, so no, I wouldn't use messaging for queries.